# Haskell Regular Expressions and Reading String as Integer

Tags: regex, haskell

Let's say I want to consider input of the form

```
[int_1, int_2, ..., int_n]
[int_1, int_2, ..., int_m]
...
```

where the input is read in from a text file. My goal is to obtain the maximum size of this list. Currently I have a regular expression that recognizes this pattern:

```
let input = "[1,2,3] [1,2,3,4,5]"
let p = input =~ "(\\[([0-9],)*[0-9]\\])" :: [[String]]
```

Output:

```
[["[1,2,3]","[1,2,3]","2,"],["[1,2,3,4,5]","[1,2,3,4,5]","4,"]]
```

So what I'm after is the max of the third index + 1. However, where I'm stuck is trying to consider this index as an int. For instance I can refer to the element just fine:

```
(p !! 0) !! 2
> "2,"
```

But I can't convert this to an int, I've tried

```
read( (p !! 0) !! 2)
```

However, this does not work despite the fact that

```
:t (p !! 0) !! 2
> (p !! 0) !! 2 :: String
```

Appears to be a string. Any advice as to why I can't read this as an int would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again.

Comment: You don'n need to convert to integer values if you need the length of the lists.

Using `length $ (read "[1, 2, 3, 4 ,5]" :: [Int])` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that your approach is one I'd recommend, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around the goal, so I'll just answer the question.

The problem is that `read "2,"` can't just produce an Int, because there's a leftover comma. You can use `reads` to get around this. `reads` produces a list of possible parses and the strings left over, so:

```
 Prelude> (reads "2,") :: [(Int,String)]
 [(2,",")]
```

In this case it's unambiguous, so you get one parse from which you can then pull out the int, although regard for your future self-respect suggests being defensive and not assuming that there will always be a valid parse (the Safe module is good for that sort of thing).

Alternatively, you could modify your regex to not include the comma in the matched group.